# not getting angular ui bootstrap popover

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to get the popover on my `<a>` on hover as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/PfEaz/14/) inside a custom directive.But its not getting me the popover.what has gone wrong here.Check the fiddle to see my entire directive definition.

```
 template: '<h1><a  popover-placement="bottom" popover="sd"  popover-trigger="mouseenter">{{pages}}</a></h1>',
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add UI Bootstrap dependency. So your module definition should be:

```
var MyDirectives = angular.module('testapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/PfEaz/15/

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do two things :

1. Add Module dependency so that it angular able to find popover
2. Add css for bootstrap for better visual

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="testapp">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrlr">
        <div mdpagination pages="pages"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var MyDirectives = angular.module('testapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

MyDirectives.controller('testCtrlr', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.pages = 'hover me to get popover'
}]);

    MyDirectives.directive("mdpagination", function () {
        console.log('DIRECTIVE!');
        return {
            template: '<h1><a popover-placement="bottom" popover="sd"  popover-trigger="mouseenter">{{pages}}</a></h1>',
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'A',
            // scope: {pages:'@'}, //default
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                console.dir(scope.pages);
            }
        }
    });
```